# Wait that an Asynchronous call in a Scala application terminate

Tags: mongodb, scala, asynchronous, playframework, future

i'm writing a Play 2.3.2 application using reactivemongo driver (with Scala).
I write a method that search the most used tag in my db and update the max and tagFound variables.

```
def max = Action {
  var max: Int = 0
  var tagFound: Tag = null
  //obtain all the tags in the db.
  val futureTags: Future[List[Tag]] = Tags.all.toList
  futureTags map{ (tags: List[Tag]) => 
    tags map { (tag: Tag) => 
      //create the tag String 
      val tagName = tag.category  + ":" + tag.attr 
      //search in the db the documents where tags.tag == tag.
      val futureRequests : Future[List[recommendationsystem.models.Request]]= Requests.find(Json.obj("tags.tag" -> tagName)).toList
      futureRequests map { (requests: List[recommendationsystem.models.Request]) =>
        //get the numbers of documents matching the tag
        val number: Int= requests.size
        if(number > max) {
          max = number
          tagFound = tag
        }
        println(max)
      }
    }                           
} 

println("here max = " + max)
//create the json result.
val jsonObject = if(max > 0) Json.obj("tag" -> tagFound, "occurencies" -> max) else Json.obj("tag" -> "NoOne", "occurencies" -> 0)
  Ok(jsonObject)
}
```

But there is a problem, from the println instruction i can see that is executed the `println("here max = " + max)` before the `futureTags map{ (tags: List[Tag]) =>...` statement. So i think that the second is an asynchronous call.
From the println statement i can see that the first print value is `here max = 0`.
So how can i wait that the `futureTags map{ (tags: List[Tag]) =>...`  finished before executed the last statements of the method?? what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to wait, you may use [Away.result](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Await$):

```
val result = Await.result(futureTags, 1 second)
```

But better way is using `Action.async` as described in [docs](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.2/ScalaAsync), so you can directly return `Future(Ok(jsonObject))`:

```
def max = Action.async {
  val futureTags: Future[List[Tag]] = Tags.all.toList
  futureTags map{ tags =>
    ...
    Ok(jsonObject)
  }
}
```